# Using jquery for grid-template-areas

Tags: jquery, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to dynamically set the values of a css grid's grid-template-area feature using jQuery, but need to use a variable instead of just writing out the string...

```
var row_one = "a a a"
var row_two = "b b b"
var row_three = "c c c"
```

and then some version of:

```
$("#page").css('grid-template-areas', 'row_one row_two row_three');
```

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Comment: `Any thoughts on how to make this work?` what have you tried to make this work?

Comment: Every variation of double and single quotation marks -- around each individually, around the set of them, around none, etc.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it was of any help. If not just comment with a follow-up question. Also be sure to have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There are a few rules to make this work:

- all have to be in one line
- there need to be outer quotes surrounding all rows
- every row has to be in their own set of quotes as well
- you have to use " for one and ' for the other

Like this: `$("#page").css('grid-template-areas', '"nav nav nav" "main main main"');`